# how do I find thresholds or crossover points in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column with values ranging from + to - in cycles. For the closest negative phases before and after an event I need to find the rows which come closest to 0, thus defining each negative phase.

[image: sample data]
<sub>(source: [enchantedspirit.org](https://www.enchantedspirit.org/images/Catweasels_Toys/Selection_013.png))</sub>

I need to find the first negative entry (1491801300) and then the subsequent first positive entry (1493850780). If I have an idea where to start with this table, I believe I can narrow the search to + or - 720 rows at each end with the results from another table.

Comment: You might want to add some sample data (best in the form of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements) and the expected results, as well as your attempts to get those results so far.

Comment: Thank you, @mustaccio - I was  clueless when I posed my question. I've not attempted any query yet, because at my (lack of) skill level I'd need to search over 500,000 entries.

Answer (score 0):

It smells like `id` and `lstamp` are really saying the same thing?  If so, do you "need" both?  For now, I will assume you abandon `id`...

Given that you have an index on `lstamp`, then this will find the first negative entry:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE mercurys < 0
    ORDER BY lstamp
    LIMIT 1;
```

That will read all the rows, starting with the oldest, until the first negative.  And, if you have `PRIMARY KEY(lstamp)`, it will be quite efficient.

If you fetch that into your application, you can see the `lstamp` and any columns that you did not mention.  Let's say you keep the `lstamp` in $lstamp (talking PHP or Perl syntax), now to find the 'next' positive:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE mercurys > 0
      AND lstamp > $lstamp
    ORDER BY lstamp
    LIMIT 1;
```

Yes, each query will be scanning lots of rows, but that's what databases are good at.  Even 500K rows won't be "too slow".  (It will be that slow if there are no negative values.)

To do both at once:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE mercurys > 0
      AND lstamp > ( 
          SELECT lstamp
            FROM tbl
            WHERE mercurys < 0
            ORDER BY lstamp
            LIMIT 1;
                   )
    ORDER BY lstamp
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I have not had a chance to test your answer properly; something else came up, far more important. At a quick glance, I think I can work with this, but I won't get to it for a few more days. Then I will either accept your answer or ask more questions.